# iOS "cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget" doesn't work in search field delegate method

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have a problem with method `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` not being executed in `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol method `textDidChange`.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    SEL updateSelector = @selector(updateTableViewWithSearchPhrase:);

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:updateSelector object:searchText];

    [self performSelector:updateSelector withObject:searchText afterDelay:0.5f];
}
```

I have clicked a keyboard button for 5 times in a row quickly, and the method was called 5 times in a row. Where is the problem, hm?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably in your test the search text is different each time. So the cancel request won't match because you haven't made a request with that object yet.

Instead use:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:updateSelector object:nil];
```

to wildcard match the selector and target.

Note it's often better to use a timer for this kind of thing than cancelling perform selectors...